# How to easily find what variation of <common command> is used in my distribution?

Tags: command-line, command, man, version, distributions

When learning to use basic C functions and other commands (sed, awk and a lot more) in terminal, shell, etc. I realize that their behavior is slightly different depending on the OS. MacOS, Linux and BSD have subtle differences and so do different distributions due to GNU extensions as well as security hardening by developers. How can I know what version my system is using without digging dozens of web pages?

`man` doesn't help. For example `man printf` states `NOTE: your shell may have its own version of printf, which usually supersedes the version described  here. Please refer to your shell's documentation for details about the options it supports.`

Answer (score 0):

In most Bourne-like shells,

```
type cmd
```

(same as `command -V cmd`) will tell you what the shell will interpret `cmd` as:

```
bash-5.2$ type time
time is a shell keyword
```

`time` in that case is a word in the syntax of the shell syntax grammar, you'd run `info bash time` to learn more about it.

```
zsh$ type ls
ls is a shell function from /home/stephane/.zshrc
```

`ls` was redefined as a function in my shell startup file. You can see its definition with `functions ls` / `typeset -f ls` or `which ls` (short for `whence -c ls`) in `zsh`.

```
ksh$ type r
r is an alias for 'hist -s'
```

In ksh93, zsh or bash, `type -a cmd` can go further and tell you all the variants of `cmd` it can discover among keywords, aliases, functions, builtins and executables in `$PATH` (and/or in their hash table of executables).

```
bash-5.2$ type -a time
time is a shell keyword
time is /usr/bin/time
time is /bin/time
```

```
zsh$ mac:~$ type -a echo
echo is a shell builtin
echo is /home/stephane/bin/echo
echo is /bin/echo
```

In the tcsh shell, you'd use `which cmd` instead which gives more details than `type` (also works in zsh, zsh's `which` also supports the `-a` option).

For the variants of a command found as an executable in the file system, you may sometimes find more than one when:

- a variant was installed as part of some third party software. Like via homebrew on macos.
- the system supports several standards and lets you choose which to conform to in your environment by setting `$PATH` like on Solaris where you can install some XPG4 or XPG6 module to enable POSIX compliance (different versions thereof), and have `/usr/xpg6/bin` or `/usr/xpg4/bin` ahead of `/bin` in `$PATH` to get the standard  versions of the executables. `man standards` will tell you how to get to their documentation.
- you have installed some variants yourself in a directory you have write access to such as `~/bin` and added it to `$PATH`.
- the system administrator has installed a variant locally like in `/usr/local/bin`.

In those cases, `$MANPATH` may also have been updated for `man` to look in for documentation in related directories. `man -a` can bring up all the man pages for a topic.

On Debian and derivatives there can be alternative implementations of a command available. For instance, you can get the `locate` command from GNU findutils or from mlocate or plocate. If more than  one package is installed, the sysadmin can run the `update-alternatives` command to select which is the one used by default, the other alternatives can still be invoked by a different name (such as `locate.findutils`) and the man page can always be accessed via that other name.

Details can be seen by running `update-alternatives --display`. e.g.

```
$ update-alternatives --display locate
locate - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/plocate
  link currently points to /usr/bin/plocate
  link locate is /usr/bin/locate
  slave locate.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/locate.1.gz
  slave updatedb is /usr/bin/updatedb
  slave updatedb.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/updatedb.1.gz
  slave updatedb.8.gz is /usr/share/man/man8/updatedb.8.gz
/usr/bin/locate.findutils - priority 20
  slave locate.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/locate.findutils.1.gz
  slave updatedb: /usr/bin/updatedb.findutils
  slave updatedb.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/updatedb.findutils.1.gz
/usr/bin/plocate - priority 90
  slave locate.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/plocate.1.gz
  slave updatedb: /usr/sbin/updatedb.plocate
  slave updatedb.8.gz: /usr/share/man/man8/updatedb.plocate.8.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of commands get some option you can use in order to output the information you are looking for. You mentioned *sed*, *awk*, try them with the --version argument :

```
Tux ~ $ awk --version
awk --version
GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1
```

Please note that the dedicated option might not always be *version*, `yourcommand -h` should generally tell you, if not the refer to the manpage.

To this matter, you are correct writing that there is a problem which some shell built-in commands like `printf` which won't normally produce any information :

```
Tux ~ $ printf --version
bash: printf: --: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

Although being written in the manpage that *printf* hounors the --version parameter.
You can infer from this that you are using the built-in *printf* function and not the one coming with the *coreutils* package, version you can use firing its full path :

```
Tux ~ $ which printf
/usr/bin/printf
Tux ~ $ /usr/bin/printf --version
/usr/bin/printf --version
printf (GNU coreutils) 8.32
Packaged by Gentoo (8.32-r1 (p0))
```